# Error reading contacts in Xamarin Forms using Xamarin.Mobile

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mobile

I am getting the below error while looping through the contacts in Xamarin.Forms android project

"Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Xamarin.Contacts.Contact]' cannot be used for return type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Xamarin.Contacts.Contact]'"

Interestingly I found the same error in bugzilla, but no resolution is mentioned.

Could someone please help me in fixing the error

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=35244

Below is the method:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<MobileUserContact>> All()
    {

        if (_contacts != null) return _contacts;

        var contacts = new List<MobileUserContact>();

        try
        {
            if (!await _book.RequestPermission())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Permission denied");
                return;
            }

            foreach (Contact contact in _book.OrderBy(c => c.LastName))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", contact.FirstName, contact.LastName);
                contacts.Add(new MobileUserContact(contact.FirstName, contact.LastName, ""));
            }

            return contacts;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

it is using Xamarin.Mobile 0.7.1.0 version dll

I have enabled Read_Contacts permission

Comment: I think you can try to include https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Mobile in your source and do some debug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a `Xamarin.Mobile` package issue, maybe you can submit an issue [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Mobile/issues). Here I cannot fix this error but can only suggest two workarounds not using this `Xamarin.Mobile` package to get Contacts.

1. You can try to use [ContactsPlugin for Xamarin and Windows](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ContactsPlugin) to get contacts.

And your `MobileUserContact` should be a class when you code like this `var contacts = new List<MobileUserContact>();`, but you use it like a method here: `contacts.Add(new MobileUserContact(contact.FirstName, contact.LastName, ""));`.

Anyway, I created a demo tried to reproduce your issue, the following code works fine by my side:

```cs
public List<MobileUserContact> contacts;
public async Task<IEnumerable<MobileUserContact>> All()
{
    contacts = new List<MobileUserContact>();
    try
    {
        if (!await CrossContacts.Current.RequestPermission())
        {
            return null;
        }

        foreach (var contact in CrossContacts.Current.Contacts.ToList())
        {
            contacts.Add(new MobileUserContact
            {
                FirstName = contact.FirstName,
                LastName = contact.LastName
            });
        }
        return contacts;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

`MobileUserContact` class is simple here:

```cs
public class MobileUserContact
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Besides the `READ_CONTACTS` permission, we also need to pay attention that this plugin only targets API 23+ and compile against API 23+ for Android platform.

The advantage uses this package is that all codes can be placed in PCL, but this package is **Currently in Alpha and not fully supported at this time**.

2. Another method is to use `DependencyService` and use the native API of Android platform to get contacts.

The code in native Android project can be for example like this:

```cs
var cursor = Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver.Query(Phone.ContentUri, null, null, null, null);
contacts = new List<MobileUserContact>();
while (cursor.MoveToNext())
{
    contacts.Add(new MobileUserContact
    {
        FirstName = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(Phone.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName)),
        Num = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(Phone.Number))
    });
}
```